# Meaning of 'pedal' in sentence?

Tags: verbs, errors, meaning

What does the following sentence mean:

> “Mattan and the yellow jersey were right in the middle of the pack as it peddled hard in the blistering heat.”?

I don't understand what "peddle" means in this sentence, taken from Longman's Dictionary of Contemporary English 5th edition.

Comment: Should we guess this has a cycling context? Can you give a link to the quote?

Comment: Are you sure that's not _pedaled_?

Comment: It's a bicycle race - it should be "pedaled", as terdon said.  The yellow jersey is the leader, as described here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_classification_in_the_Tour_de_France

Comment: It means you are looking at sample sentences written by non-native speakers of English: https://www.google.com/search?q="Mattan+and+the+yellow+jersey"

Comment: It is an example of the word peddle on the Longman's Dictionary of Contemporary English 5th edition

Comment: I didn't mispell it. It's how it appears on the Longman's Dictionary of Contemporary English 5th edition. It must be an error of the dictionary.

Comment: @Pedro Try looking at the alternative spelling 'pedal' or see this link               http://www.training4cyclists.com/cycling-pedalling-frequency-%E2%80%93-fast-or-slow/

Answer (score 3):

This is a common mis-spelling, it should be *pedaled* ie pressing on the pedals of a cycle - cycling, in other words!

*To peddle* means to sell, especially travelling from door to door. A *pedlar* is one who *peddles*, but it's an old-fashioned term now.

Comment: unless it's a Freudian slip, with the drugs on the Tour etc.

Comment: no it is not mis-spelled.. here is the sentence http://www.sentbase.com/snt/?q=blistering%20heat/amn&corpus=juk

Comment: @JavaD: the original writer misspelled *pedalled* (or didn't know the difference).

Comment: @TimLymington..have you any proof? I don't think so?

Comment: @JavaD your link takes the sentence out of context but all the circumstantial evidence points to it being a cycling reference  - the yellow jersey, the pack (of cyclists) and pedalling hard in a race. Therefore the original writer has mis-spelled 'peddled'. The alternative is that Mattan and a yellow jersey were in the middle of a pack (of people? wolves? cards?) which was trying very hard to sell something in the blistering heat. Which one makes more sense?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you check your spelling.

The following are excepts from [**Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English**](http://www.ldoceonline.com/) online:

> **pedal** [2](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/pedal_2)
> *past tense and past participle* **pedalled**, *present participle* **pedalling** *British English*,
> *past tense and past participle* **pedaled**, *present participle* **pedaling** *American English*
> (intransitive and transitive)
>
> 1. [always + adverb/preposition] to ride a bicycle
>    **pedal up/along/down etc**
>    *Andrew pedalled up the road towards the town centre*.
> 2. to turn or push the pedals on a bicycle or other machine with your feet:
>    She was **pedalling furiously** (=very fast).
>
> **peddle** (transitive) [3](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/peddle)
>
> 1. to sell goods to people, especially goods that people disapprove of because they are illegal, harmful, or of not very high quality:
>    *They were accused of **peddling drugs**.*
>    *people who peddle cigarettes to young children*
> 2. to try to sell things to people, especially by going from place to place:
>    *Farmers come to Seoul to peddle rice*.
>    *a door-to-door salesman **peddling his wares*** (=selling his goods)
> 3. to try to persuade people to accept an opinion or idea which is wrong or false:
>    *politicians peddling instant solutions to long-standing problems*

Comment: Pedro commented: "I didn't mispell it. It's how it appears on the Longman's Dictionary of Contemporary English 5th edition. It must be an error of the dictionary." Perhaps they've since fixed the online and newer print editions.

Comment: @Hugo Yes, but you will note that Pedro's comment was 3 days **later** than my answer.

Comment: I did note that, just adding it for any other readers :)